# Why scanf llu doesn't validate %llu?

Tags: c, validation, scanf

I'm using `scanf("%llu%c", &myUnsignedLong, &checkerNewLine)` to validate a number `>0 && <2^64`, where `checkerNewLine` is used to clear the buffer if someone try to insert a letter ( `while (getchar() != '\n');` ).

But if I try inserting a negative number, like `-541231`, `scanf` succeed and return 2 ( as the number of parameters matched ). Obviously the number stored in `myUnsignedLong` is `2^64-541231`, but it is NOT my intention.

Any simple way to solve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your intention then?

Comment: @haccks Presumably the OP expected that `scanf("%llu")` would fail to parse the negative number and would return an error.

Answer (score 4):

From the specification (7.9.16.2):

> **`u`** Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with the value 10 for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.

Note that the input is optionally signed. This explains why the code behaves as it does.

However I can't offer any good explanation for why it's specified this way. Since you can't store a negative value in an unsigned variable in a well-defined way, I suspect that this may actually invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Most probably it will invoke UB.

Comment: So I can't validate in any way a value in a range: every time I insert a value that respect MIN < myValue%(2^(4*sizeof(unsigned long long int))) < MAX is always valid, right?